Call custom hook only on the active component in the DOM
My goal is to detect a click outside of the components using this custom hook:
const useOutsideClick = (callback) => {
  const reference = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = (event) => {
      if (reference.current && !reference.current.contains(event.target)) {
        console.log(reference.current);
        console.log(event.target);

        callback();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  }, [reference]);

  return reference;
};

I have a <HeaderSearch /> custom component which looks like this:
const HeaderSearch = ({ screenWidth }) => {
   
  function checkInput(event) {
    if (event.keyCode !== 13) {
      setSearch(event.target.value);
    }
  }
  const mobileRef = useOutsideClick(test);
  const ref = useOutsideClick(test);

  if (location.pathname !== "/") {
    if (screenWidth == "mobile") {
      return (
        <div id="search-header" className="search-header mob" ref={mobileRef}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            className="search-icon"
            id="search-icon"
            icon={faSearch}
            onClick={() => toggleSearchInput()}
          />
          <input
            id="search-input"
            className={searchActive ? "search-input active" : "search-input"}
            type="text"
            value={search}
            onKeyDown={(e) => checkInput(e)}
            onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
            // ref={searchInputRef}
            // onClick={() => searchReqClientSide()}
            placeholder="Search..."
          />
          <button></button>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div id="search-header" className="search-header desk" ref={ref}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            className="search-icon"
            id="search-icon"
            icon={faSearch}
            onClick={() => toggleSearchInput()}
          />
          <input
            id="search-input"
            className={searchActive ? "search-input active" : "search-input"}
            type="text"
            value={search}
            onKeyDown={(e) => checkInput(e)}
            onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
            // ref={searchInputRef}
            // onClick={() => searchReqClientSide()}
            placeholder="Search..."
          />
          <button></button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

The HeaderSearch component is displayed conditionally by CSS classes. If parent header element has class "active" change display of header without active to display "none".
However when I click outside of the component, the custom hook is still being called for both of the HeaderSearch components. See screenshot below:

How can I make it that only the <HeaderSearch/> which is active calls the useOutsideClick hook instead of both firing every click?
Here is the test callback, it's a simple log:
function test() {
  console.log("clicked outside");
}


Have you considered not mounting the HeaderSearch component that isn't in use by conditionally rendering it rather than using CSS to show/hide it?

"The custom hook is still being called for both of the HeaderSearch components" - well your code is calling it twice. Why not just use one ref only, and attach it to the currently rendered div?

@NickParsons {isMobile ? <HeaderSearch screenWidth="mobile" /> : null} fixed the issue

Refactor the logic such that only one useOutsideClick hook is necessary. Since the header content, i.e. the children, appear to be same for both mobile and desk view, you can refactor to replace the wrapping div elements with a single div that conditionally applies the correct CSS className prop, and any other layout/UI differences between mobile and desk views.
Example Implementation:
const HeaderSearch = ({ screenWidth }) => {
  const ref = useOutsideClick(test);
  ...

  function checkInput(event) {
    if (event.keyCode !== 13) {
      setSearch(event.target.value);
    }
  }

  if (location.pathname !== "/") {
    return (
      <div
        ref={ref}
        id="search-header"
        className={[
          "search-header",
          screenWidth == "mobile" ? "mob" : "desk"
        ].join(" ")}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          className="search-icon"
          id="search-icon"
          icon={faSearch}
          onClick={() => toggleSearchInput()}
        />
        <input
          id="search-input"
          className={["search-input", searchActive && "active"]
            .filter(Boolean)
            .join(" ")
          }
          type="text"
          value={search}
          onKeyDown={(e) => checkInput(e)}
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
          // ref={searchInputRef}
          // onClick={() => searchReqClientSide()}
          placeholder="Search..."
        />
        <button></button>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};


@Bergi True... I think I initially went down the path of two sub-components, but then realized they render the same content and got stuck on the refactor into component path. I'll update.

Can you elaborate what  {["search-input", searchActive && "active"].filter(Boolean).join(" ")} does?

I solved it by conditially rendering. see comment @nick-parson

@GoldenBags It does the same thing as the original className={searchActive ? "search-input active" : "search-input"}, just avoiding the duplication and making it easier to add other (optional) classes

@GoldenBags Yes, Bergi explained the className value implementation. So were you actually also rendering two HeaderSearch components on top of each one calling two useOutsideClick hooks? You should probably render just one and pass screenWidth dynamically, like <HeaderSearch screenWidth={isMobile ? "mobile" : "desk"} />.

@DrewReese Yeah i'm rendering 2 HeaderSearch components. One for the mobile navigation(sidebar) and for desktop navigation.
